# Image Preview asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, image

I'm working on getting an `image` into a `picturebox` on asp.net from a `list-box`, the `list-box` reads a directory and then populates the `jpegs` in the file. 
This needs to be done in c#, at the moment I have a rough idea on how it's done but I'm not getting any picture showing:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          DirectoryInfo infoDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"G:/Test_Directory");            
          FileInfo[] infoFile = infoDir.GetFiles("*.jpeg");
          foreach( FileInfo file in infoFile )
          {
               lstDirectory.Items.Add(file.Name);
          }
        }    
    }

    protected void lstDirectory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        Server.MapPath(lstDirectory.SelectedValue.ToString());
        imageChange.ImageUrl = lstDirectory.SelectedValue.ToString();            
    }
}
```

it could be a case of the path not being correct, or maybe something else. Can someone could direct me to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the result of `MapPath`. Try this.

```
    var img = Server.MapPath(lstDirectory.SelectedValue.ToString());
    imageChange.ImageUrl = img;
```

**UPDATE:** Your image files folder seems to be outside of web folder, move it inside. There is no simple way to make it work otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked, I think the page is reloading every time I click on an item in the listbox, meaning that it becomes null again, and therefore the picture has a null value. Which would be an error with my PostBack?

Comment: What string do you see in `img` while debugging?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked again, it's gone into the wrong folder G:\\ConsoleApplication1\\Task3\\jpegimage.jpeg    where as it should be G:\Test_Directory\jpegimage.jpeg

Comment: There is no sense in making path to be local to your computer, it should be URL, absolute or relative.
Lets say you move your files in `images` folder under your web root folder. then you should pass `"/images/"+fileName` to ImageUrl

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to `add New folder` in your solution and `add all your images in to it...`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
          DirectoryInfo infoDir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("Images"));//this is the image foled name            
          FileInfo[] infoFile = infoDir.GetFiles("*.jpeg");
          foreach( FileInfo file in infoFile )
          {
               lstDirectory.Items.Add(file.Name,"Images/"+file.Name);
             //here you are setting relative path of images in your value field
          }
        }    
    }
```

Then set the image path to thr Server.MapPath as follow....

```
protected void lstDirectory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(lstDirectory.SelectedValue.ToString())))
        {
          imageChange.ImageUrl =Server.MapPath(lstDirectory.SelectedValue.ToString());            
        }
    }
```